# L'amour de tout délie du secret (ou les secrets)

Tags: paroles-de-chanson, inversion

*Question corrigée pour faire mention de la version originelle.*

---

J'ai récemment découvert la chanson « Aimer est plus fort que d'être aimé » de Daniel Balavoine sur l'album *Sauver l'amour* ([vidéo](https://youtu.be/BmzfwPrS4x8), [paroles](https://www.lacoccinelle.net/287332.html)).

Voici le refrain :

> L'amour te porte dans tes efforts
>   
> L'amour de tout délie du secret
>   
> Et face à tout ce qui te dévore
>   
> Aimer est plus fort que d'être aimé

Une reprise sur l'album *Balavoine(s)* sorti en 2016 ([vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8ktKn2-_-E), [paroles](https://www.paroles.net/cats-on-trees/paroles-aimer-est-plus-fort-que-d-etre-aime)) change le deuxième vers ainsi :

> L'amour de tout délie **les secrets**

Ni l'une ni l'autre des versions me semble avoir une syntaxe très claire.

Pour la version originelle (*du secret*), j'entends peut-être :

1. Cet « amour de tout » libère (quoi que ce soit) de quelque secret

La deuxième version semble permettre deux autres analyses grammaticales :

2. Cet « amour de tout » dénoue les secrets comme les nœuds
3. L'amour dénoue les secrets de toute chose

J'ai du mal à me décider pour l'une ou l'autre. D'un côté, je ne sais pas ce que serait pour Balavoine cet « amour de tout ». De l'autre, je n'aime pas invoquer une inversion poétique gratuite. J'imagine que Cats on Trees, le groupe qui a fait la reprise, a eu des difficultés aussi, sinon on aurait laissé les paroles telles quelles.

Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Comment: Il semble qu'il y ait deux versions ; dans une autre, chose bizarre, on trouve le refrain suivant  :L'amour/Te porte dans tes efforts/L'amour/De tout, délie du secret/ Oh -et face à tous ceux qui te dévorent /Aimer est plus fort que d'être aimé( [paroles](https://www.lacoccinelle.net/287332.html)). Cela correspond au paroles chantées [ici](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=balavoine+youtube%2c+aimer+est+plus+fort&qpvt=balavoine+youtube%2c+aimer+est+plus+fort&view=detail&mid=CB606A0019A2E5DE538ECB606A0019A2E5DE538E&&FORM=VRDGAR)

Comment: @LPH Très intéressant ! That video seems to be lip-synced from the album version ([here](https://youtu.be/BmzfwPrS4x8) with better audio). Sure enough, at [3:00](https://youtu.be/BmzfwPrS4x8?t=179) I clearly hear « du secret ». Je ne sais pas vraiment comment faire l'analyse cette fois. « Délier du secret de tout » serait un non-sens — oui ? — ne nous permettant que « [C'est] l'amour de tout [qui] délie du secret » = ce qui est secret ? Ce qui veut dire ... ?

Comment: Ces vidéos ne sont pas autorisées dans ma région (France). En effet, on ne sait plus sur quel pied danser ; comme on ne peut faire autrement que de considérer que la seconde version introduit un sens différent, je crois qu'il vaut mieux s'en tenir à la première et poser une autre question pour la seconde, si suffisamment curieux de savoir ce que le refrain signifie dans celle-ci. Je ne vois pas ce que cela signifie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je pense qu'il faut comprendre :

> L'amour, de tout, délie du secret

Ce qui signifie que l'amour délie de tous les secrets.

[Délier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9lier) signifie ici:

> Libérer quelqu'un d'un engagement, d'une obligation

Les secrets dont on peut se délier sont essentiellement le *secret professionnel* et le *secret médical* mais ce peuvent être aussi les secrets *défense*, *bancaire*, *militaire*, *de l'instruction*, *de fonction*, *de la confession*, etc.

L'idée serait donc que l'amour incite à faire des confidences inconsidérées, des **confidences sur l'oreiller** comme l'écrit très justement ex-Jardin de frosted flakes (user3177).

---

En revanche, l'expression *délie les secrets* trouvée dans la reprise de 2016 n'a pas vraiment de sens.

On ne trouve aucune occurrence de *délie[r] un secret*, *délie[r] le secret* ou *délie[r] les secrets* avec Google NGram. Le seul mot apparaissant entre les formes verbales de *délier* est *secret* étant ***du***:

[image]

Comment: Un peu comme les confidences sur l'oreiller quoi ? Bien intéressant.

Comment: Merci pour les données supplémentaires ! C'est donc bizarre ce changement.

Answer (score 3):

On préfère une analyse syntaxique et grammaticale simple qui tienne la route sans réflexion ontologique ni besoin de s'appuyer sur une langue étrangère (où même là *love of all things* ne serait pas inusité à mon avis) et on préfère donc la première solution (*l'amour de tout* dans le sens *de toute chose*).

Même si l'inversion du complément déterminatif n'est pas suivie par la [virgule](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3405), pour rompre l'association naturelle du complément avec le sujet *amour* et éviter à l'auditeur de devoir rebrousser inutilement chemin, on l'aurait personnellement utilisée précédemment (*L'amour, de tout délie les secrets.*). De plus, les autres paroles du couplet avec leur syntaxe et leur vocabulaire usuel ne justifient selon moi aucune haute voltige linguistique dans la phrase en question ; il ne s'agit pas d'une poème précieux mais bien d'une chanson. Subsidiairement le collocation *l'amour de tout* est plus [fréquente](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=l%27amour%20de%20tout%2Cles%20secrets%20de%20tout&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cl%27%20amour%20de%20tout%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cles%20secrets%20de%20tout%3B%2Cc0) que celle *les secrets de tout*.

Answer (score 1):

Je crois qu'il ne s'agit que de la seconde solution ; évidemment, le pourquoi que j'entrevois est une raison assez subjective, en partie la conséquence d'une sagesse qui appartient à une autre culture ; je fais référence à un adage américain, tout au moins je pense qu'il est dû à cette partie de la culture anglo-saxonne : « Il n'y a pas de connaissance sans amour ». L'amour, c'est à dire l'amour en tant que sentiment non confiné au domaine des relations affectives humaines est donc un ingrédient essentiel, sinon le principal ingrédient qui mène au savoir, au secret des choses. Il est clair dans cette assertion qu'il n'est pas question de l'amour de tout mais seulement de l'amour en général.

Si on doit insister que c'est l'amour de tout qui est la condition préliminaire on aborde de multiples questions ; une première se pose en référence au bien et au mal ; qu'est-ce que l'amour du mal ? L'amour de la connaissance du mal ? Ne faut-il pas aimer le mal lui-même puisque il fait partie du tout ? Tout cela est assez improbable. Une seconde question n'est pas plus encourageante : s'agit-il de la nécessité d'aimer tout ce à quoi nous pouvons avoir accès dans nos activités ? Non, il est clair que nous atteignons tous un certain succès dans nos entreprises parce nous nous restreignons à des domaines particuliers ; untel a réussi dans le journalisme scientifique en raison d'un plus grand intérêt dans ce domaine, d'un amour de la science, cela à l'exclusion d'autres domaines qui n'ont suscité aucun intérêt; tel autre est parvenu à des découvertes médicales d'importance parce qu'il n'aimait pas le journalisme et qu'il s'est converti à la médecine. Donc on ne peut pas définir cet amour de tout, qui n'est toujours pas ce que l'on appelle l'amour de la vie.

Il semble y avoir peu de doute que la seconde possibilité soit la bonne.